# Overriding a specific display doesn't work

Tags: views

I created a view in Drupal 8 with 2 displays. I want to keep a display content view mode as teaser and the other as featured (custom), but when I change a display it updates the other display as well.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to miss if you're always clicking on the `| Settings` link of an Option.

Options can be set to apply to `All displays` or you can override for each Display separately `This attachment (override)`.

But you have to click on the Option itself and not its "Settings" link to see that Dropdown.

You clicked on the "Teaser" or the "Featured" Settings link of your `Show` Option, but there is no Dropdown to override there.

You have to click on the **`Content`** link first, Override through the Dropdown for this Attachment only and Apply (this display). Then you can change the Settings for the Option if you have to. It will only apply to the current Display.

You can change the original Display Option to what you want and Apply to all displays, that one doesn't have to be overridden, unless it makes sense for that particular case.

Comment: I got it.. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select content and change the setting to this attachment override.
Then select the mode.
Like the below image.

[image: Override the current view]

Comment: I got it..Thank you so much for the screenshot.